# How to render Zend_Navigation in different section in xml?

Tags: php, zend-framework

How to render Zend_Navigation in different section in xml?
Here my xml

```
<configdata>
    <admin>
        .....
    </admin>
    <default>
        .....
    </default>
</configdata>
```

I'm already testing this but render of menu get same result section admin

```
$navContainerConfig = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/navigation.xml', 'default');
$navContainer       = new Zend_Navigation($navContainerConfig);

$view->navigation = $view->navigation()->setAcl($this->acl)->setRole($role)->menu($navContainer);

$navContainerConfig     = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/navigation.xml', 'admin');
$navContainer           = new Zend_Navigation($navContainerConfig);
$view->navigationAdmin  = $view->navigation()->setAcl($this->acl)->setRole($role)->menu($navContainer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the Zend_Navigation_Container directly to the navigation view helper:

```
$view->navigationDefault = $view->navigation($defaultNavContainer)->setAcl($this->acl)->setRole($role);
$view->navigationAdmin = $view->navigation($adminNavContainer)->setAcl($this->acl)->setRole($role);
```